# Why Django cannot display images in my CSS file?

Tags: css, django

I'm having a problem in displaying images in my CSS file.

I have a css file with the following class:

```
.header
{
 margin-left: auto;
 bla bla
 bla bla
 ...
 background: url(/site_media/header_background.gif) no-repeat top left;
}
```

When I execute the template with this css, no image is displayed, but when I directly inject the background style into my template it works perfectly.

What am I not doing right?

Comment: Can you post the "bla bla bla"? A missing ";" in there could be the reason it's not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to give complete path of header_background.gif relative to your css file location to get this working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting quotes around it.

```
background: url('/site_media/header_background.gif')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys! i was using a wrong CSS file! Its working Ok, even without the quotes!, thanks **sysrqb**